# When a user logs into my Ruby app on Heroku, it seems to get stuck in a loop. This does not happen for guest users. Can anyone advise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

So, long story short - I'm comfortable with HTML, CSS, SQL a bit of Javascript etc as a hobby, but am far from a 'proper' developer. Recently a friend paid a developer to build a web app for them (the friend have no IT skills at all). The developer (who is no longer on the scene) left them with a working demo in Heroku and a GitHub repo which I have now cloned. My friend wanted some of the cosmetic bits changing, which I offered to help with, but in order to do this, I had to create my own version of the app on Heroku from my forked repo.

I couldn't get this to work, kept getting an error message when trying to deploy the app, despite the code being completely unchanged from the parent. I should mention now that the app has been written in Ruby, with which I have zero experience. But I thought I'd have a go anyway...

After much Googling, I managed to get the app to successfully deploy by changing the version of @rails/webpacker in the package.json file. I then changed any references to originalApp.herokuapps.com to myNewVersion.herokuapps.com.

After this, I had to set some Config Vars in Heroku (relating to gmail and stripe) to get things up and running. This all seemed to work ok...

So I'm now at the point where a user can sign up on the app and subscribe to the service using Stripe (test) and is successfully sent a confirmation email.

However, once a user is logged in, anytime they try to go to any other page, for example the 'About Us' or 'Contact Us' page, it immediately redirects (or stays) on the same page. There's no other pages the logged-in user can access.  However, if I log out, then the 'guest' user can navigate to the other pages freely.

Example:

If I'm logged in, the URL shows https://*myproject*.herokuapp.com/start and the contents of the page are what the user was presented with after signing up and paying the Stripe fee.

If they then click on, for example, the 'About Us' link, the log shows this (I've edited the URLs to show *myproject* instead of the real project name):

```
2022-01-05T22:16:29.805824+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.805699 #4]  INFO -- : [0efc978f-35cf-4d11-ae66-edbdb5b26ec4] Started GET "/about-us" for 90.197.167.151 at 2022-01-05 22:16:29 +0000
2022-01-05T22:16:29.806538+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.806485 #4]  INFO -- : [0efc978f-35cf-4d11-ae66-edbdb5b26ec4] Processing by PagesController#about_us as HTML
2022-01-05T22:16:29.809496+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.809430 #4] DEBUG -- : [0efc978f-35cf-4d11-ae66-edbdb5b26ec4]   [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2022-01-05T22:16:29.810151+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.810102 #4]  INFO -- : [0efc978f-35cf-4d11-ae66-edbdb5b26ec4] Redirected to https://myproject.herokuapp.com/start
2022-01-05T22:16:29.810227+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.810201 #4]  INFO -- : [0efc978f-35cf-4d11-ae66-edbdb5b26ec4] Filter chain halted as :check_subscription rendered or redirected
2022-01-05T22:16:29.810322+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.810300 #4]  INFO -- : [0efc978f-35cf-4d11-ae66-edbdb5b26ec4] Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Allocations: 964)
2022-01-05T22:16:29.835064+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.834991 #4]  INFO -- : [a7c07664-645b-449c-a9a8-a50a2c060f3b] Started GET "/start" for 90.197.167.151 at 2022-01-05 22:16:29 +0000
2022-01-05T22:16:29.835712+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.835663 #4]  INFO -- : [a7c07664-645b-449c-a9a8-a50a2c060f3b] Processing by CheckoutsController#start as HTML
2022-01-05T22:16:29.836943+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.836887 #4]  INFO -- : [a7c07664-645b-449c-a9a8-a50a2c060f3b]   Rendering checkouts/start.html.erb within layouts/application
2022-01-05T22:16:29.839055+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.838940 #4] DEBUG -- : [a7c07664-645b-449c-a9a8-a50a2c060f3b]   [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2022-01-05T22:16:29.839685+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.839609 #4]  INFO -- : [a7c07664-645b-449c-a9a8-a50a2c060f3b]   Rendered checkouts/start.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.6ms | Allocations: 401)
2022-01-05T22:16:29.841324+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.841270 #4]  INFO -- : [a7c07664-645b-449c-a9a8-a50a2c060f3b]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 905)
2022-01-05T22:16:29.841552+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-01-05T22:16:29.841516 #4]  INFO -- : [a7c07664-645b-449c-a9a8-a50a2c060f3b] Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Allocations: 2433)
2022-01-05T22:16:29.816017+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about-us" host=myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=0efc978f-35cf-4d11-ae66-edbdb5b26ec4 fwd="90.197.167.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=302 bytes=1393 protocol=https
```

As said, I'm not familiar with Ruby at all, but I suspect it's something to do with the lines that mention:

```
Redirected to https://myproject.herokuapp.com/start
Filter chain halted as :check_subscription rendered or redirected
```

You can see it's trying to go to the /about-us page but it remains on /start.

I believe the app uses something called 'Devise' for the user registration process.

Given the code is the same as the parent repo that I forked from, I'm guessing the issue is either a setting within Heroku or some kind of variable that I'm missing or have not updated.  If anyone can advise me on next steps with regards to research or a solution, I'd be very grateful. I appreciate I'm no expert, but I'm just trying to do a friend a favour after they've been left hanging by another dev. Many Thanks.

**Update:**

application_controller.rb

```
      before_action :authenticate_user!, :halt_if_mobile
      before_action :check_subscription, except: %i[ home start ]
    
      def halt_if_mobile
        if browser.device.mobile?
          render inline: "Mobile access is currently disabled"
          return
        end
      end
    
      def check_subscription
        return unless current_user
        return if controller_path =~ /devise/ || controller_path =~ /registrations/
        
        if !current_user.active
          redirect_to start_path, notice: 'Please update your payment settings'
          return
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: So it sounds like there is a check, possibly this `check_subscription` thing.  Can you share the code related to that?  There should be something like this somewhere `before_action : check_subscription`. Either in a controller or the application controller.  Then in that file there will be a method `def check_subscription`.  Can you share the code for that method?  OR just share a link to the github repo if you can (your version though), that might help in this instance as well

Comment: Thanks for this - so I have checked and can see that `check_subscription` appears in the `application_controller.rb` and in `checkouts_controller.rb`.  Presumably the checkouts_controller.rb relates to the process of signing up and subscribing using Stripe.

application_controller.rb:

```class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :halt_if_mobile
  before_action :check_subscription, except: %i[ home start ]
```

Comment: Ya but what is the code in the method?   There is a method somewhere `def check_subscriptions` and I suspect it has a redirect based on subscription status.  That will. let you know where the issue is. Also, please edit the question to include it, do not paste the code into a comment if you need help with it.

Comment: Thanks - I've added the code from the ```application_controller.rb``` which features the ```def check_subscriptions``` method.

Comment: Based on your error it looks like `if !current_user.active` is getting triggered.  What is `.active` on a User mean?  It appears that what you experiencing is because your user (you) is triggering the conditional `!current_user.active` which leads to the redirect to the start path, You are also seeing the message `Please update your payment settings'`, correct?

Comment: One thing to add, if you want to test what I am saying, just remove that before action related `before_action :check_subscription`.  You might get errors but if the page URL does change and try to load a different URL then you know that is the issue.